# BeautifulSoup data-reactid Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Tried using data-reactid markers to search Yahoo Finance for a number, but I get a `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`. My code:

```
Walmart stock
source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WMT?p=WMT&.tsrc=fin-srch').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
price = soup.find('span', data-reactid_='35')
print("Walmart stock: " + price.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just do in wrong way a little. In my view, it is more flexible to use dict than something like `class_=`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WMT?p=WMT&.tsrc=fin-srch').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
price = soup.find_all('span', {"data-reactid":True})
print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'e6Rbk-YUCGHVbt5kDAh_'

# get the table for daily stock prices and,
# filter the table for selected tickers, columns within a time range
# set paginate to True because Quandl limits tables API to 10,000 rows per call

data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = ['WMT'], 
                        qopts = { 'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'adj_close'] }, 
                        date = { 'gte': '2015-12-31', 'lte': '2016-12-31' }, 
                        paginate=True)
print(data)
```

This is probably worth a look too.

https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/WMT.csv?api_key=your_api_key-oges_here